# Edit API function to filter by all selected filters, rather than only most recent one

Tags: javascript, angular, mongoose, eventemitter

I have built a function that handles filtering data based on a series of checkbox filters that users can click on in my Angular app. Right now I've got the function working to the point that whenever one of four filters is selected, the data will filter based on that selection. However, when a user clicks the next filter, while the data filters to match this request, it LOSES the previous filter.

In other words, it only filters based on the most recent filter selection. How can I edit this function so that it filters for ALL presently selected filters? Here is the function I currently have:

```
onFilterReceived(value, type) {
    if (type === 'lan' && value) {
        this.streamFiltersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
            "services.workflow.status" : "visiting",
            "languages.primary" : { $in: value }
            })
            .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                this.records = resRecordsData;
                console.log('Visiting onLanguageReceived language: ' + value + ' type: ' + type);
            },
            responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
    } else if (type === 'dis' && value) {
        this.streamFiltersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
            "services.workflow.status" : "visiting",
            "services.service" : { $in: value }
            })
            .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                this.records = resRecordsData;
                console.log('Visiting onDisciplineReceived discipline ' + value + ' type: ' + type);
            },
            responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
    } else if (type === 'zip' && value) {
        this.streamFiltersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
            "services.workflow.status" : "visiting",
            "addresses.postalCode" : { $in: value },
            })
            .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                this.records = resRecordsData;
                console.log('Visiting onZipcodeReceived: ' + value + ' type: ' + type);
            },
            responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
    } else if (type === 'branch' && value) {
        this.streamFiltersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
            "services.workflow.status" : "visiting",
            "branch" : { $in: value }
            })
            .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                this.records = resRecordsData;
                console.log('Visiting Branch ' + value + ', type: ' + type);
            },
            responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
     } else {
        this.streamFiltersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
            "services.workflow.status" : "visiting"
        })
            .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                this.records = resRecordsData;
            },
            responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
    }
}
```

I am sending the events through from one component to another using Angular's Output() and EventEmitter(). The template view for that looks like this:

```
        <list [records]="records" 
            (sendBranch)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'branch')"
            (sendZipcode)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'zip')"
            (sendLanguage)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'lan')"
            (sendDiscipline)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'dis')">
        </list>
```